# Ordering one array column with respect to another array column in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have below table in Bigquery -

```
WITH results AS
  (SELECT 1 as customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] as fruit_array, [0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2] as probability
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] as fruit_array, [0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1] as probability
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] as fruit_array, [0.5,0.05,0.35,0.1] as probability
  )
 select * from results
```

Here, each customer has a certain probability of purchasing a fruit. I would like to pick up `top 2` fruits for each customer and their corresponding `probabilities` of purchase.

It would be nice to have output similar to something like this -

```
customerid, fruits, probability
1, bananas, 0.4
1, grapes, 0.3
..
```

In the above end result, for `customerid 1` I only pick up `bananas` and `grapes` because these 2 fruits have highest probabilities of purchase ( from `[0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2]` )

Is there any function which I can use in BiqQuery to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH results AS (
  SELECT 1 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2] AS probability   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1] AS probability   UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.5,0.05,0.35,0.1] AS probability
)
SELECT customerid, fruit, probability
FROM (
  SELECT customerid, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(fruit, probability) ORDER BY probability DESC LIMIT 2) top
  FROM results, 
    UNNEST(probability) probability WITH OFFSET off1
    JOIN UNNEST(fruit_array) fruit WITH OFFSET off2
    ON off1 = off2
  GROUP BY customerid
), UNNEST(top)
```

with result

```
Row customerid  fruit   probability  
1   1           bananas 0.4  
2   1           grapes  0.3  
3   2           grapes  0.6  
4   2           apples  0.2  
5   3           apples  0.5  
6   3           grapes  0.35
```

or might slightly be better option

```
#standardSQL
WITH results AS (
  SELECT 1 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2] AS probability   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1] AS probability   UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS customerid, ["apples", "bananas", "grapes","orange"] AS fruit_array, [0.5,0.05,0.35,0.1] AS probability
)
SELECT customerid, fruit, probability
FROM (
  SELECT customerid, 
    (
      SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(fruit, probability) ORDER BY probability DESC LIMIT 2) 
      FROM   UNNEST(probability) probability WITH OFFSET off1
      JOIN UNNEST(fruit_array) fruit WITH OFFSET off2
      ON off1 = off2
    ) top
  FROM results
), UNNEST(top)
```

with the same result